# Descriptive statistics for 2 variables grouped by gender with spss

Tags: data-visualization, spss, descriptive-statistics, pre-post-comparison, bland-altman-plot

I have 3 variables one categorical `gender` and the others are the `IQBefore` and `IQAfter` which are the `IQ` collected for the same person before and after playing a game.

**I need to make a descriptive statistics for the IQBefore and IQAfter (grouped by gender) comparing its descriptive effect on each gender.**

what I did is:

using spss: `Analyze > Descriptive statistics > Explore`

in the `Explore` box, I have chosen `IQBefore` and `IQAfter` in the `Dependent List`, while `gender` in the `factor list`.

I just want to know is there anything I'm doing wrong or need to add to accomplish my descriptive test and are the proper graphs 'Histogram' and 'Stem-and-leaf' to represent them?

Answer (score 1):

For such data I would start out with visualization, in this case a Bland-Altman plot (or Tukey mean-difference plot.) For an example, see [Bland & Altman plot for repeated measures using one measuring device](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169145/bland-altman-plot-for-repeated-measures-using-one-measuring-device).

In this case, maybe plotting on the x axis the `IQbefore`, and on the y-axis the change score `IQafter-IQbefore`.  Then color the points according to gender.

For more advice see [Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs).